# PrepareForSegue issues

Tags: ios, xcode

I have the 3 methods below using storyboard where I have a "segue" connect from my "View Movie Info" button to my next view. The identifier is "web"

When I click on the button I call this method:
(IBAction)synopsis:(id)sender then this method calls -> 
(void)fetcheMovie:(NSData *)responseData and then it should go to (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)jason

On the prepareforsegue method I put a nsslog on the "jsonSendetAsParamInPerformSegue" and I get two logs

1: UIRoundedRectButton: 0x9595c60; frame = (11 322; 298 44); opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; layer = CALayer: 0x9595d30

2->My json  results ( what I expect )

and below i get this:
2013-05-09 18:55:06.185 drigo[840:c07] nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for .
Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.

I need to get one of the values from the json and pass it to my next view

The methods are below.. Please help.. I've been stuck for couple of days on this

```
- (IBAction)synopsis:(id)sender {
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/%@?api_key=34eb86f3b94de2676e8d3007b5ce1993",movieid];
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetcheMovie:)withObject:data waitUntilDone:NO];
    });
}

- (void)fetcheMovie:(NSData *)responseData {
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData  options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    news = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData  options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"web" sender:news];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)jason {
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary *jsonSendetAsParamInPerformSegue = (NSDictionary*)jason;
    NSLog(@"%@",jsonSendetAsParamInPerformSegue);
    //WebViewController *targetVC = (WebViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    //targetVC.newsArticles = jsonSendetAsParamInPerformSegue;
}
```

Comment: Seems like an issue with your storyboard to me,  I can't see It so am not really sure but try and change the segue from push to modal in the storyboard and see what happens.  Edit (by storyboard, I mean the way you are segueing to view controllers in the storyboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should connect the segue from the source ViewController to the destination ViewController, don't connect it from the button.

If you connect it from the button, when you click the button, it performs the segue(the sender is the button), then in your code you call perform segue again, that is why it's wrong.

Comment: I did connect from the View Movie Info to the webviewcontroller, maybe  it is why I get 2 nsslogs on for the button and the other one the one I really need, but I don't know what I need to do to fix it,,, Help !!!

Comment: Sorry, I mean you should connect the segue from the source ViewController to the destination ViewController, don't connect it from the button. see my updated answer

Comment: sorry itebean, you meant I shouldn't use the segue from the interface builder? should do it on the code itself?

Comment: No, I mean in the storyboard, you should connect the segue from the source controller to the destination controller, don't connect it from the button on the source controller to the destination controller

Comment: Thanks... it worked greate, you can't believe how much you helped me.